# thymeleaf + bootstrap + css - why is my last image NOT aligned to the end?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am working on a header fragment I want centralized on the screen

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand">
    <div class="container-fluid col-8">
        <div class="w-100">
            <div class="row align-middle">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/logoA.gif}" alt="logoA" height="50" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 navbar-brand text-white text-center">
                    <h4><strong><span th:text="#{gen.appName}"></span></strong></h4>
                    <span th:text="#{gen.appNameLong}"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-end">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/logoB.png}" alt="logoB" height="50" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

While I don't have a very active menu so far, I want to have the header centralized in the page. This was the best I could manage. `navbar-custom` just sets a background color.

My issue is that the image logoB is always aligned to the start of its `<div />` and I want it to be aligned to the end.

I am sure I am doing something really stupid. UI is not my bread and butter.

How can I get this working as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a bit and got it working with:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand">
    <div class="container-fluid col-8">
        <div class="w-100">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/logoA.gif}" alt="logoA" height="50" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-10 navbar-brand text-white text-center align-middle">
                            <h4><strong><span th:text="#{gen.appName}"></span></strong></h4>
                            <span th:text="#{gen.appNameLong}"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                            <a href="#" th:href="@{/swagger-ui.html}">
                                <img th:src="@{/images/swagger.svg}" alt="swagger" height="100" width="100" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                    <img th:src="@{/images/logoB.png}" alt="logoB" height="50" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```